# Building a Response object from JSON data for Mocking

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I created json data as below and also created related pojos to access the data

```
{
   "name":"Joy",
   "Location":"Sydney",
   "appsCreated":{
      "timerApp":{
         "apkVersion":"0.1",
         "store":"playStore"
      }
   }
}
```

I want to mock the value in my test like below

```
 Mockito.mock(responseData.getAppsCreated().getTimerApp().getApkVersion()).thenReturn("0.2");
```

My test case throws NullPointerException, because My object data is null ,what would be the proper way to Build objects and access data from JSON when mocking .

Comment: Generally you shouldn't mock a constant.

Comment: Then how can you mock the data to give different values ?

Comment: did you previously mock `responseData`?

Comment: You don't mock data, you mock behavior. You would make an object with your data and return it from a database call (repository find, etc), api call(resttemplate get, etc) or even an internal service (myservice.calulateTotal, etc)

Comment: responseData is an object here

Comment: responseData is an object with null value for your tests.

Comment: How are you writing test, which is mock what is injected what are you trying to mock, pelase give more information, wht runner you are using, is it controller or service, mock mvc?

Comment: I am writing test for a controller which will check responseData for any possible error values and spits out the error responses, I have some conditions in my logic in the controller which will check for values All I am trying to do is mock those object values , so that I can easily verify the logic inside the controller ,the only Mock injected is basically the request object which will be processed by the controller , I am using the MockitoJunitRunner.

Comment: aran you are correct , when I debugger points out the responseData object is null , I am trying to mock this object.